# iOS: set delegate to NSObject from Delegate file

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have this problem:

I'm using a library which is assigned a delegate from the delegate file. This is the original sample code:

```
[[TGAccessoryManager sharedTGAccessoryManager] setDelegate:(RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

and the view controller where is implemented this delegate have this code:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <TGAccessoryDelegate>
   code
@end
```

So, in another project I implemented a NSObject similar to previous code, something like this:

```
@interface neuroskyEngine : NSObject <TGAccessoryDelegate>
   code
@end
```

I tried to set delegate into the same object in the init code with this:

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){                
        [[TGAccessoryManager sharedTGAccessoryManager] setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and create an object with `neuroskyEngine *element = [[neuroskyEngine allot] init];` but it doesn't works for me.

How can I set up correctly the delegate from delegate file?

Comment: How does a `neuroskyEngine` object get created?

Comment: @Philip Mills With neuroskyEngine *engine = [[neuroskyEngine alloc] init];. I updated my question with that detail.

Comment: You should be able to write: `[[TGAccessoryManager sharedTGAccessoryManager] setDelegate:engine];` once you create it.  Assigning the delegate inside the `init` should also be fine.  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Do you keep the `engine` variable around to act as a delegate?